# Dynamically add .js file, how to know when it's ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, load

In order to only load the jquery swipe script in touch devices, I am detecting it with modernizer and appending the script if is touch, like this:

```
/**/
if ( modernizer.touch ) {
    var js = jQuery("<script>");
    css.attr({
      type:  "text/css",
      src: base_url + "/js/jquery-touch-swipe.js?p1"
    });
    $("head").append(css);
    $this.swipe( function( e, dx, dy ){
        if( dx < 0 ){
            $this.find('.next').click();
        } else {
            $this.find('.prev').click();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that right after, the function `swipe` isn't ready yet. I could use a `setTimeout` but I couldn't be sure either,

How can I make sure the appended script is ready?

I tried like this:

```
    if ( modernizer.touch ) {
        var js = jQuery("<script>");
        css.attr({
          type:  "text/css",
          src: base_url + "/js/jquery-touch-swipe.js?p1",
          id: 'swipe'
        });
        $("head").append(css);
        $('#swipe').load(function() {
            $this.swipe( function( e, dx, dy ){
                if( dx < 0 ){
                    $this.find('.next').click();
                } else {
                    $this.find('.prev').click();
                }
            });
        });


}
```

But with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) and the use its success callback function which will execute once script is loaded but not necessarily executed.

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    $.getScript(base_url + "/js/jquery-touch-swipe.js?p1", function () {
        //Operation which you want to perform
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Now I just have to deal why `Modernizer` is undefined.. thanks!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, use `Modernizr.touch` instead of `modernizr.touch`, There was a typo which we missed

Comment: yes yes, I tried... I don't understand why, the .js file resolves.. I guess is a whole different issue anyways.. thanks!

Comment: oh my god! I just realized there is no `e`, `moderni` `zr` and not `moderni` `zer`!!!